# Prove that eventually the numbers will stop changing.

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> **QUESTION:** Several positive integers are written on a blackboard. One can erase any two distinct integers and write their greatest common divisor and least common multiple instead. Prove that eventually the numbers will stop changing.

---

**MY ANSWER:** I came across this question lately.. and I progressed upto some extent after which I couldn't think further. As we know,

*LCM$×$HCF= product of the numbers*.
So applying that concept we can see that the product of the numbers never changes on the blackboard. But how do I prove that the numbers themselves will stop changing?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that you make a change by choosing $a$ nad $b$. WLOG if $a \leqslant b$, then $\gcd(a,b) \leqslant a \leqslant b \leqslant \text{lcm}(a,b)$. As $\gcd(a,b) \cdot \text{lcm}(a,b) = ab$, it is not hard to see that $\gcd(a,b)+\text{lcm}(a,b) > a+b$ in case of an actual change. This means that a change increases the sum of all the numbers on the board.

Now, assume that the numbers on the blackboard actually change infinitely often. For each change, we make the sum of the numbers on the board bigger since the sum of the GCD and LCM will be greater than the sum of the two numbers. However, if there are infinitely many changes, then the sum of the numbers will go off to $\infty$. Can this happen?

If the sum goes of to $\infty$, then the largest number must go off to $\infty$ as well. Obviously this is false as the product of all the numbers is constant and finite.

Comment: Do we not need to show that gcd$+$lcm$≥$$(a+b)?$

Comment: We do. I assume you can do it. If not, do tell me and I will include the reason in my answer or as a comment.

Comment: Nah... I got it.. thank you for your help.. you did a lot :) @Haran

Comment: Try to show that if $xy=ab$ and $x < a \leqslant b < y$ then $x+y>a+b$. Then just replace $x=\gcd(a,b)$ and $y=\text{lcm}(a,b)$.

Comment: Yeah I got you. Thanks again:).. @Haran

Answer (score 0):

If a step makes a change, then $\gcd(a,b)+\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)<a+b$ (why?)

Comment: You've got the inequality reversed.